# angularjs ng--show is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am getting wrong behaviour with my ng-show directives.

```
<span class="spanLabel" ng-show="!minimumCharactersMet()" >You need at least {{ howManyMoreCharactersNeeded() }} characters more</span>
<span class="spanLabel" ng-show="isNumberOfCharactersWithinRange()" >Remaining characters: {{ howManyCharactersRemaining() }}</span>
<span class="spanLabel warning" ng-show="anyCharactersOver()" >{{howManyCharactersOver()}} characters too many</span>
```

When I try to input a text span is counting from below to warn user of 2 characters minimum, countdown works and after stays there and does not hide. Also second one does not show.

Here is my [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuCIxKvK8voXfHu0DuTy) with all the functions and html.
Any ideas why I cant get it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @Reins said, the two other statements have these errors:

- You're missing the same *function-calling* brackets on `anyCharactersOver`
- The return statement in the `howMany` functions has a bracket error. It should be

  `return ( characters < 0 ? Math.abs(characters) : 0);`
- Also, the return value of `isNumberOfCharactersWithinRange` should be:

  `$scope.minimumCharactersMet() && !$scope.anyCharactersOver();`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fvzBmSqZyYmPuwxw5l2j?p=preview)

PS: I'd use `ng-hide` instead of `ng-show(!)`

Comment: `characters < 0 ? Math.abs(characters) : 0` is the same as `Math.abs(characters)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though your boolean is wrong. The minimumCharactersMet() boolean should call for a function on the scope. Like this:

```
$scope.minimumCharactersMet = function() {
    return ($scope.howManyMoreCharactersNeeded() === 0);
};
```

Notice the braces after the howManyMoreCharactersNeeded call. Otherwise it would be as if you were asking for a variable not a function.

[working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2tfnzkgtvyuljpDcOxPs?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. rlecaro2 's post has all the errors that is why I expected that. I dont know it is the right thing to do in SO

Comment: @ytsejam, you should accept the answer that helped you the most.